# Cannot convert instance of class org.jruby.RubyObject to class java.lang.String

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp

I am trying to  add a field to set @timestamp timezone match my timestamp
I have tried adding timezone to filter, but it doesn't help.

original timestamp looks like ,

```
"@timestamp" => "2016-06-08T01:36:42.655Z",
```

My date filter is:

```
mutate {
add_field => [ "localtime", "%{@timestamp}" ]
}
date {
  locale => "en_US"
  timezone => "America/New_York"
  match => [ "localtime", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"]
 target => "localtime"
 }
```

and get the warning  _dateparsefailure

am i missing anything ? 
can anyone please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: In your `match`, isn't `"timestamp"` supposed to be `"@timestamp"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your match needs to work on a different field than `@timestamp`, which is not a string and is thus not parseable. Since you've copied `@timestamp` into `datetime`, you can now use `datetime` in your `match`.

```
mutate {
    add_field => [ "datetime", "%{@timestamp}" ]
}
date {
    locale => "en_US"
    timezone => "America/New_York"
    match => [ "datetime", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"]
    #match => [ "datetime", "ISO8601"]  # <- you can also use this 
    target => "datetime"
}
```

Comment: "datetime" => "2016-06-08T03:54:03.635Z",
                                   "tags" => [
        [0] "_dateparsefailure"
    ],

Comment: Weird, I get no `_dateparsefailure` in my case.

Comment: Are you certain you're using the exact same filter as mine?

Comment: No more `_dateparsefailure` then

Comment: Can you update your question with your full config and a sample log line so I can recreate the problem on my side?

Comment: What about a sample log line?

Comment: I'm asking for a **raw sample log line** that comes from your `snmptrap` input

Comment: add raw sample input

Comment: Not what I'm asking for. I just need the raw `message` field.

Comment: that's raw message field content

Comment: Maybe I should have asked earlier, but what version of Logstash are you running?